# Turning a whole block of code into a line in C

Tags: c

Say for example I want to enter this whole block of code into a command:

```
int k = 0;

for (k = 0; k < 50; k++) 
{
    sprintf(buf, "M LR 10 -10\n");                     //We put the string "M L 10" into the string buffer.
    write(sock, buf, strlen(buf));                     //We send the buffer into the socket.
    memset(buf, 0, 80);                                //Clear the buffer, set buffer to value 0.
    read(sock, buf, 80);                               //Read from the socket to get the results.
    int lme, rme;
    sprintf(buf, "S MELR\n");                          //sensor command to find ME values
    write(sock, buf, strlen(buf));                     //sends the buffer to the socket
    memset(buf, 0, 80);                                //Clear the buffer, set buffer to value 0.
    read(sock, buf, 80);                               //read from socket to get results.
    sscanf(buf, "S MELR %i %i\n", &lme, &rme);         //takes lme and rme values from results
    printf(buf, "%3i   %-4i\n", lme, rme);
    //distance = 2 * (22/7) * r
}

for (k = 50; k < 51; k++) 
{
    sprintf(buf, "C RME\n");                           //We put the string "C RME" into the string buffer to reset.
    write(sock, buf, strlen(buf));                     //We send the buffer into the socket.
    memset(buf, 0, 80);                                //Clear the buffer, set buffer to value 0.
    read(sock, buf, 80);                               //Read from the socket to get the results.
}
```

that enables me to just change the value of the string in `{sprintf(buf, "M LR 10 -10\n");}` i.e. `10` and `-10`, and the rest of the process will carry out by itself:

for example, `set_motor_speed(10 -10\n)` in the main code would carry out the whole function, how to do it?

Comment: This is a _really_ basic question, of the sort better addressed by a basic programming textbook than an online Q&A site.  The term you're looking for in C is "function definition", but if you don't already know that, you probably shouldn't be coding in C at all - it's much too low-level for beginners.

Comment: If only there was a way in C to perform a certain `function` over and over again....bah, that's just a pipe dream.

Comment: Sometimes we even want a function *not* to be called over and over again...

Comment: We need "General Reference" reason for closing questions

Comment: [c Functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/)

Comment: Wrap this code in a function having two parameters, that you call with (10,-10). Replace in the *sprintf*s where `10` and `-10` are with `%d` and add the parameters. E.g. `void set_motor_speed(int i1, int i2) { ... }`, and `sprintf(buf, "M LR 10 -10\n");` => `sprintf(buf, "M LR %d %d\n", i1, i2);`

Comment: @Zack too low-level for beginners? I think it's rather almost too high level for beginners. :)

Answer (score 5):

As the others have said: you can read about this sort of thing in a C-language book, but hey we are nice:

```
set_motor_speed(int a, int b) {
    ...
    for(k = 0; k < 50; k++) {
        sprintf(buf, "M LR %i %i\n", a, b);
        ...
    }
    ...
}

set_motor_speed(10, -10);
set_motor_speed(5, -5);
```